# How to send and receive a generically typed object in a list

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to create a class in which I have two override functions via an interface. The interface will be generically typed and I want the functions to simple be conversions.

I've been able to make this work, however, when I create multiples of these objects and put them into a list and access them singularly then the function that should take the generic type as input gives the error: `Type mismatch: inferred type is Any but Nothing was expected`

In other words:

```
interface ConverterInterface<T>{
    fun sender(value: T): ByteArray
    fun receiver(bytes: ByteArray): T
}
```

And this does work when first implemented:

```
class TestClass {
    val objA = object: ConverterInterface<String>{
        override fun sender(value: String): ByteArray {
            //...
        }

        override fun receiver(bytes: ByteArray): String {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

However, I want to store a list of these objects and access them later.

```
fun test(){
    val testList: List<ConverterInterface<*>> = listOf(objA)

    // This works
    testList[0].receiver(byteArrayOf())

    // This does not
    testList[0].sender("")
    /* Out-projected type 'ConverterInterface<*>' prohibits the use of
    'public abstract fun sender(value: T): ByteArray defined in ConverterInterface */
}
```

I had to use the wildcard `*` for the list type because if I tried to use `Any` I would get a type inference failed error. To make it work I could set the type as `out Any` but this doesn't fix anything and causes only the `receiver` function to work.

I feel that what I'm trying to do may not be possible. Simply put I want to be able to access these functions without doing type casting.

Comment: NOTE: It is necessary that these objects are being stored in a list because the way I am using them they are being created at run time. I'm well aware that accessing the object directly will give me the result I want but that is not my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to do a bit of redesign here.  The compiler is warning you about a serious type-safety problem in your code, and if you don't fix it properly, it's likely to come back to bite you.

You have a `List` of converters, but you can't tell what each one can convert; each one implements the `ConverterInterface<T>` for *some* type `T`, but you don't know what `T` is for any particular item in the list.

`testList[0]` (assuming the list has at least one item) could implement `ConverterInterface<String>`, or `ConverterInterface<Int>`, or `ConverterInterface<Map<URL, LinkedList<LinearGradientPaint>>`, or anything else.  So it's not safe to `testList[0].realSender("")`, because it might not accept a String.

That's why the compiler complains; it doesn't know anything about the type involved, so it has to assume the worst case, and disallow the call.  Otherwise, you'd risk a `ClassCastException` at runtime when the converter couldn't handle the type of parameter you pass it.

Even worse, due to type erasure, you can't find out that type at runtime, either.  (At runtime, after the compiler has done its magic, there's only a simple `ConverterInterface`.)

By the way, the answer with a `realSender()` isn't fixing this problem, just telling the compiler to shut up about it.  It'll still bite you at runtime.

So I think you'll need to think more carefully about what you're trying to achieve here.

Why are you storing these converters in a list, and why do you need to access them that way?

If you you know every implementation will be able to accept Strings, then make the list a `List<ConverterInterface<String>>`: the compiler will ensure that everything in the list can take Strings, and you can then safely pass a String to any converter in the list.

But if the list could contain different types of converter, then how will you know that the converter you're looking at can take any particular type?  Even if the code works for now, there's still a risk that an extra item will get inserted into the list later on, and screw things up.  So you'd have to keep track some other way.  And that other way would probably give you a better (typesafe) way to access them.

Comment: I'm storing these objects in a list because they are created at runtime. I'm working on an Android Module that contains a Service to handle BLE interactions. I'm trying to figure out a way that the user of the library can create their BLE periphial's properties, give them to the service, and then when the service either reads or writes the bytes it will be converted for the user instead of having to hardcode the implementation. (Essentially when something is read, an id comes with it which will be used to find the correct conversion object)

Comment: I think I'm going to have to scrap this idea. I just can't find any way to make it work or at least work safely.

Comment: I'm still not certain quite what's needed, but as I said, there may be ways to keep track of the types involved — for example, instead of having a List, you could have a Map from a class object to a converter handling that class.  Or you could add a getter method to your converter which returns the relevant class object.  You'd probably still need to tell the compiler to ignore an unsafe cast, but in that case you could be sure it would always work.

Comment: The big issue is that the converters being created are not one size fits all. There will more than likely be multiple converters of the same type. The converter will have an id which will be used to find the correct converter from the list. So in theory, the cast should always succeed and if not it would be at the fault of the programmer.

Comment: It might be possible.  But there's a long history of programmers thinking they know better than the compiler, and being proved wrong…  (For example, IIRC JetBrains did some research on the use of the `!!` operator, which tells the compiler “Ah, but I _know_ this can never be null.  Honest.  Trust me!”, and found that surprisingly often the value _is_ null after all.  I'm sure similar things happen when type-casting too.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this even a good solution but here is what I have come up with. I've created an abstract class that implements the interface but also contains a predefined function for the sender that casts to `T` internally:

```
interface ConverterInterface<T>{
    fun sender(value: T): ByteArray
    fun receiver(bytes: ByteArray): T
}

abstract class TestClass<T> : ConverterInterface<T>{
    fun realSender(value: Any): ByteArray{
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return sender(value as T)
    }
}

val testObj = object: TestClass<String>(){
    override fun sender(value: String): ByteArray {
        return byteArrayOf()
    }
    override fun receiver(bytes: ByteArray): String {
        return ""
    }

}

val testList: List<TestClass<*>> = listOf(testObj)

fun a(){
    testList[0].realSender("")
    testList[0].receiver(byteArrayOf())
}
```

I understand that the function now accepts whatever is put into it and that this could cause exceptions, but as of the moment this is all I can come up with as a solution. Also, in my case at least, the class's functions should never receive anything other than their generic so a value of a different type being passed in would truly be an exception.